# Which database is better to use with electron windows build

Tags: database, windows, electron, desktop-application, electron-packager

i am developing a standalone school management application using electron framework ,which database is better in my scenario. i mean the database should easy to manage ,easy to distribute with the application package or easy to configure it in any system. What i want to store is student details,fee details,images. etc,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use classic Mysql with an ORM like [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2).If you want to use local databases, I advise you to use **sqlite**. It's very easy to manage and to be distributed.

**Some useful links :**

- [Sqlite for NodeJS with example](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/)
- [Data persitence / SQL for Electron app](https://www.techiediaries.com/electron-data-persistence/)

Comment: yeah  ,actually i tried it but it got me some errors like module not found etc, what about mongoDb ?